# How to wait during ajax call?

Tags: extjs

I am creating a window from a view controller when an image is clicked from view.This window consist of some fields and send button. When some one click on the send button ajax call will go to server and server will take time to respond back till the response comes... I want to show a message with background blurred like "Please wait processing your request" and once response comes, message box should be closed and some operation should be done on the basis of response.
How should I do it?

I would be helpful if some code snippet will be there.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest to handle it like below.Write below line of code inside the function from where you are making ajax request.Set mask just before the ajax request and unmask it on response from server,whether it is failure or success.

```
Ext.Viewport.mask({ xtype: 'loadmask',message: 'Please wait processing your request' });

Ext.Ajax.request({
  //set your ajax request parameter
  success: function(response, opts) {
    Ext.Viewport.unmask();
  },
  failure: function(response, opts) {
    Ext.Viewport.unmask();
  }
});
```